# Subclass SKSpriteNode without a color (Swift 2.0)

Tags: swift, migration, uicolor, skspritenode

Yesterday i did the migration to swift 2.0.
I noticed that the Color in the only suitable Designated Initializer:

```
init(texture: SKTexture?, color: UIColor, size: CGSize)
```

does not support nil. In other words there must be a texture (if desired) AND a color.

The only solution i come up with is to pass a UIColor.clearColor() to the init method, but is it a good one, or do i miss something?

Thx